# Is there a way match background/text color for current theme?

Tags: javascript, css

When forcing a theme with `color-scheme` is there a way to match the actual text/background color?
Background color `Canvas` and text color `CanvasText` don't quiet match the actual theme colors (in Edge/Chrome dark theme it shows as black color, while actual color is lighter) and when theme switched via javascript these colors don't reflect the changes (see "My Groupbox" label after clicking checkbox):

```js
Math.floor(Math.random()*2)&&document.querySelector("input").click();
```

```css
:root
{
  color-scheme: light;
}

.groupbox
{
  border: 1px solid rgba(127, 127, 127, 0.5);
  display: grid;
  padding: 1em 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.groupbox > label
{
  position: absolute;
  top: -0.5em;
  left: 0.5em;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding: 0 0.4em;

  color: CanvasText;
  background-color: Canvas;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" oninput="documentElement.style.colorScheme=this.checked&&'dark'"> Dark theme</label>
<div class="groupbox">
  <label>My Groupbox</label>
  <h1>My Header</h1>
  <span>My Text</span>
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I could find is changing the html elements to work better together and not using the Canvas & CanvasText css attributes. It seems like Canvas and CavasText won't change with the scheme and stick to their default colors.

Basically, I just replaced the wrapping `<div>` element with a `<fieldset>` and replaced `<label>` with `<legend>`, giving the same exact result but now you don't have to worry about the background or text color. It also allowed me to remove some css that was no longer needed.

the `<fieldset> & <legend>` work well together and you don't have to worry about the border line crossing through your text like it was doing with the `<div> & <label>` element.

```js
Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) && document.querySelector("input").click();
```

```css
:root {
  color-scheme: light;
}

.groupbox {
  border: 1px solid rgba(127, 127, 127, 0.5);
  padding: 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" oninput="documentElement.style.colorScheme=this.checked&&'dark'"> Dark theme</label>
<fieldset class="groupbox">
  <legend>My GroupBox</legend>
  <h1>My Header</h1>
  <span>My Text</span>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip.  Unfortunately can't accept the answer, as I'm more interested in how to actually get proper colors...

Comment: I think this article can help you. The author uses the System Colors such as Canvas & CanvasText to change the color-scheme. In his method he is able to match the Canvas and CanvasText colors to the System colors as well as update it on color-scheme changes. They also go further to make it uniform across all browsers at the end of the article as well. here is the link: https://blog.jim-nielsen.com/2021/css-system-colors/